# Why a diode is in parallel with the current source in the equivalent circuit of a solar cell?

Tags: diodes, solar-cell, current-source, circuit-design

The [model of a solar cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_solar_cells#Equivalent_circuit_of_a_solar_cell) has a diode *in parallel* to the current source:
[image]([source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_cell_equivalent_circuit.svg))

Why is the diode in parallel and not **in series** with the current source?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm four years late, but none of the other answers here acknowledges that the diode in the model actually is real. A conventional PV cell **IS** a giant PN diode, and the current source in the diagram models the fact that photons absorbed near the junction cause electrons to cross the junction going the "wrong way." In the absence of any external circuit, those electrons then cross back as normal forward current in the diode, causing the characteristic "forward voltage" of the diode to appear as \$V\$.

Answer (score 1):

The diode in the model is telling you that the output voltage of the cell is limited. A diode in series wouldn't limit the output voltage at all, and that is not the way the cell behaves.

Comment: How is the parallel diode limit the output voltage? Just by reducing the "effective R_shunt"?

Comment: The model is a "model". It gives you a means of modelling the behaviour mathematically and in simulations. What you can read into the model is that when open circuit: \$I_L\$ will cause \$V_{SH}\$ to rise. As it does the diode becomes forward biased. Due to the non-linear behaviour of diodes the current through the diode will rise exponentially with \$V_{SH}\$ and will, effectively, limit the output voltage to the diode's forward voltage. Just to state the obvious, all the components are inherent in the manufacture of the cell. They're not added into it.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the diode in parallel and not in series with the current source?

Frankly: Because that wouldn't fit the model of a solar cell.

The current through that diode goes exponential with the voltage across it; so the higher your output load resistance, the smaller the amount of current of   \$I_L\$ that is available at the output.

Answer (score 0):

The diode effectively determines the maximum output voltage you can get out of the pv cell. The diode starts conducting after a certain voltage has built up across it (forwards voltage). Letting current pass through, the diode actively limits the available voltage to its forward voltage. This is a more realistic model of a pv cell than an ideal current source because in real life, you cannot draw arbitrarily great voltages out of the pv cell.